# On Facebook is it possible to force an app to display as a page tab?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app the currently consists of 3 elements - an App on Facebook, Mobile Web, and a Page Tab.

Currently if I use the app URL it detects whether I am on a mobile or not and directs me to either the app on Facebook or the mobile web site.

What I'd like it to do is always show the app in the context of the page tab. Is there anyway to force this?

I tried looking at whether I could use the page tab URL directly and have that redirect to the mobile but depending on how I've linked it either returns a 404 or just takes you to the Facebook page. I appreciate I could do my own mobile detection but I thought I'd check if I'm missing something in Facebook first.

Comment: To help provide some context we have a client who wants to post a link on their page that will take the user to either the page tab or the mobile site depending on the device they're on.

Comment: This is an explanation for what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856438/mobile-users-unable-to-access-facebook-page-tab/15860533#15860533

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an explanation of how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434072/create-facebook-page-tab-and-publish-template-on-it/14455665#14455665

Hope this is what you are after!